# How to use a large number of 3d models

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

Currently I'm having problem in using multiple models in SceneKit. I have a 1MB  3d object file which is in .dae format. When I try to use a large number of these (let's say 1000 models), memory of the app rises and the app crashes. I even used scene kit inbuilt functions `clone()` and `flattenedClone()` for making copies of the models. What shall I do?

Comment: i think scenekit particle system can complete your work

Comment: can you please elaborate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a lot of vertices to be pushing around. Do you really need them all loaded at once? Can you simplify the model?

Creating `SCNLevelOfDetail` instances will help a bit. That's illustrated in AAPLSlideLOD.m in the WWDC 2014 SceneKit slides sample code.

```
NSMutableArray *levelsOfDetail = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSUInteger i = 1; i < 5; i++) {

    SCNNode *teapotNode = [self.groundNode childNodeWithName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Teapot%lu", (unsigned long)i] recursively:YES];
    SCNGeometry *teapot = teapotNode.geometry;

    // Unshare the material because we will highlight the different levels of detail with different colors in the next step
    teapot.firstMaterial = [teapot.firstMaterial copy];

    // Build the SCNLevelOfDetail instance
    SCNLevelOfDetail *levelOfDetail = [SCNLevelOfDetail levelOfDetailWithGeometry:teapot worldSpaceDistance:distances[i - 1]];
    [levelsOfDetail addObject:levelOfDetail];
}

teapot.geometry.levelsOfDetail = levelsOfDetail;
```

Comment: Yeah thats right, I got to load all the model at once. How many models can I load if levelofdetails is used? If app is optimized at its full, how many models does it can render?

Comment: How long is one piece of string? iPhone 6S or original iPad Mini? Seriously, that answer depends on lots of things. But why do you need 1000 high resolution models visible in 12 square inches?

Comment: Thank you so much Hal. I highly appreciate your answer. But what I wanted is not all high resolution models, but it can be less detailed model which should something look like the original model. Just wanted to show thousands of models into a scene. Is there any other idea for doing the same?

Comment: That's exactly what levelOfDetail is about. You'll have to tinker, though, because the precise limits/ranges are not documented. Try it. If it doesn't work, you should unaccept my answer, in hopes of encouraging someone else to weigh in.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a technical answer, it's more of a description of how to manage polygon complexity and presentation.

LOD = Level of Detail, and whilst it's a technical term in Scene Kit and other 3D applications and frameworks, it's worth taking a moment to think about the three words as harbingers of sensitivity to equipment and viewer/user perception.

Ask yourself what level of detail do your models need at any given distance from the camera view point.

The answer will be different depending on distance, complexity of models and the lighting and materials you use.

Ever since 3D art on computers was first conceived and created, everything is a "hack" in presentation to deceive the viewer at the limits of hardware.

And we still are limited (greatly) by the hardware.

So it's well worth the time investment to discover all these hacks of detail/complexity and perception.

Some of them are:

- Texture baking
- Smoothing vertices
- LOD Swapping
- Normal Mapping/baking
- Back face culling

And many others.

Perhaps the best place to start is here:

http://www.katsbits.com/tutorials/blender/baking-normal-maps-from-models-advanced.php

As this will give you an idea just how much thought and consideration goes into optimisation with consideration to perception in just one aspect of the technical design that is 3D model presentation.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this like

```
int numberOfSpheres = 20;

for(int i=0;i<numberOfSpheres;i++) {


    NSURL *itemUrl = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"yourResourceScene" withExtension:@".dae"];
    SCNSceneSource *source = [SCNSceneSource sceneSourceWithURL:itemUrl options:nil];
    SCNGeometry *nodeGeometry = (SCNGeometry *)[source entryWithIdentifier:@"objectInScene" withClass:[SCNGeometry class]];

    SCNNode *myNode = [SCNNode nodeWithGeometry:nodeGeometry];

    [MainScene.rootNode addChildNode:myNode];
    // set position for each node here
    // set scale of each node here

    // set material of each node here

}
```

Comment: How about an explanation of what your code is doing? This just adds 20 spheres to a scene but doesn't answer the question.